# Is there an easy way to check for duplicate shortcut keys?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I recently ran into a situation with a Winforms application where a single shortcut key was firing multiple events due to the same key being mapped to more than one control. Is there an easy way to search for such duplicate keys in the application? I recognize that it's likely to come up with false positives for cases that can't happen, such as mutually exclusive dialogs sharing the same key, but it would be nice to at least have a starting place.

Best bet I can think of at the moment is to search the resource files for the `.ShortcutKeys` data and then process the results of that, but that seems a bit over-involved.

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Comment: @EricScherrer Honestly? Not really. I needed to check for the shortcuts within the same application, not for all applications running on the computer.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Does this need to be done at runtime, without knowing a priori what is bound? Do you actually need the key bindings, or do you need to prevent certain events from firing?

Comment: @EricScherrer A compile-time check would be fine, or an automated test. Mainly, I'm trying to figure out how to avoid this happening in the future. With so many developers, it's far too easy to accidentally re-use a shortcut and not realize until long after the software has been fielded.

Comment: @SeanDuggan were you responding to my comment or Eric's again? Anyway, I would suggest an alternate approach. Have the desired/focused control capture the key and handle it so it's not passed to the rest of your application. The KeyPress event is available to any control that inherits from the base Control class (which should be everything), thus the KeyPressEventArgs are exposed to you. Check here if your shortcut is key(s) are activated; if so, handle it and return. If not, pass it along.

Comment: The bonus is you should be able to assign the same keys for an arbitrary amount of different controls, so shortcut re-use shouldnt be a problem unless you need it to be global. In that case, don't handle it on the control level.

Comment: @glace Sorry. Totally missed that the names had changed. I'll check to see if that works for this case. It's one of the applications where people expect legacy behavior, so I'm a bit more constrained.

Comment: By legacy behavior, do you mean one hotkey does the same thing, regardless of application context? i.e. ctrl+shift+N launches the nuke no matter what I'm doing in the application?

Comment: @SeanDuggan it wouldn't be all applications - GetProcessesByName will only return the application you ask for. A compile time check will not work as these properties get assigned at run time. If you are doing any sort of automated UI testing on check in you will have the process running, just grep it there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the System.Windows.Automation library to enumerate the shortcuts. Here is a quick and dirty example that looks at task manager. You will have to add a reference to UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr").FirstOrDefault();

        var condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, process.Id);

        AutomationElement window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);

        AutomationElementCollection descendents = window.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);

        foreach (var descendent in descendents)
        {
            var foo = descendent as AutomationElement;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo.Current.AcceleratorKey))
                Console.WriteLine(foo.Current.AcceleratorKey);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo.Current.AccessKey))
                Console.WriteLine(foo.Current. AccessKey);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(descendents.Count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

---

Alt + Space

Alt+F

Alt+O

Alt+V

Alt+H

11